# Android slow socket reading

Tags: java, android, performance, sockets

I'm trying to create an app, which records audio from microphone and sends it via a socket to a server on another phone. To simulate another phone I'm currently using a ServerSocket on localhost. Now I do know, that I probably won't get not choppy 44100Hz, Stereo, PCM_16BIT audio on the server without some crazy compression, but the transmission speed of my socket is ridiculously low. I get around 16kB/s. On localhost!

This is my client (runs in a service as two threads):

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> audioQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(100);
boolean isRecording;

int sample_rate = 44100;
int buff_size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sample_rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

void recorderThread_func() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    int s_read;
    byte[] tmp_buff;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buff_size];

    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            sample_rate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            buff_size);
    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;

    while (isRecording) {
        tmp_buff = new byte[buff_size];
        s_read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buff_size);
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, tmp_buff, 0, s_read);

        audioQueue.put(tmp_buff);
    }

    isRecording = false;
    recorder.stop();
}

void socketThread_func() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    byte[] tmp_buffer;

    Thread.sleep(250);

    Socket audioSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2004);
    OutputStream out = audioSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = audioSocket.getInputStream();
    out.flush();

    tmp_buffer = new byte[]{
            (byte) 0xde,
            (byte) ((buff_size >> 24) & 0xff),
            (byte) ((buff_size >> 16) & 0xff),
            (byte) ((buff_size >>  8) & 0xff),
            (byte) ((buff_size      ) & 0xff)};
    out.write(tmp_buffer, 0, 5);
    out.flush();

    long a;
    long b;
    long c = 1;
    long d = 1;
    while (isRecording) {
        tmp_buffer = audioQueue.take();

          a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        out.write(tmp_buffer, 0, buff_size);
        out.flush();
          b = System.currentTimeMillis();
          c += b-a;
          d++;
          System.out.println("speed=" + ((1000*buff_size*(d++))/c));

        in.read(tmp_buffer, 0, 1);
        if (tmp_buffer[0] != (byte)'A')
            break;
    }

    isRecording = false;
    out.flush();
    audioSocket.close();
}
```

And this is my server code (runs in two separate threads):

```
int buff_size = 0;
boolean isPlaying;

LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> audioQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(100);

void socketThread_func() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    byte[] msg = new byte[5];
    byte[] tmp_buffer;
    int s_read;

    ServerSocket audioSocket = new ServerSocket();
    audioSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(1024 * 1024 * 16);
    audioSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2004));

    Socket connSocket = audioSocket.accept();
    OutputStream out = connSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = connSocket.getInputStream();
    out.flush();

    in.read(msg, 0, 5);
    if (msg[0] != ((byte)0xde)) {
        return;
    }
    buff_size = ((int)msg[4] & 0xff) + (((int)msg[3] & 0xff) << 8) + (((int)msg[2] & 0xff) << 16) + (((int)msg[1] & 0xff) << 24);
    msg = new byte[buff_size];
    System.out.println("read: " + buff_size);

    isPlaying = true;

    long a;
    long b;
    long c = 1;
    long d = 1;
    while ( isPlaying ) {
          a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        s_read = in.read(msg);
          b = System.currentTimeMillis();
          c += b-a;
          d++;
          System.out.println("speed_sv=" + ((1000*buff_size*(d++))/c));
        if (s_read == -1)
            break;

        tmp_buffer = new byte[buff_size];
        System.arraycopy(msg, 0, tmp_buffer, 0, s_read);
        audioQueue.put(tmp_buffer);

        out.write('A');
        out.flush();
    }
    isPlaying = false;

    connSocket.close();
    audioSocket.close();
}

private static void playerThread_func() throws InterruptedException{
    byte[] tmp_buffer;

    Thread.sleep(750);

    AudioTrack mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sample_rate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            buff_size,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    mAudioTrack.play();

    while (isPlaying) {
        tmp_buffer = audioQueue.take();
        mAudioTrack.write(tmp_buffer, 0, buff_size);
    }

    isPlaying = false;
    mAudioTrack.stop();
}
```

The code is a bit a mess due to my attempts at figuring out why is it so slow. It's probably some sort of silly mistake but I just can't see it.

EDIT: I've modified the code so that now it has different threads for recording/playing and socket handling. It turns out, that the sending part of the code is working just fine, at high speeds, which are just enough to transmit even 44100Hz audio (through 127.0.0.1). But the server's in.read() function seems to be what's slowing everything down.

> speed=272243612
>
> speed_sv=459849

Comment: Record first then send. Dont record and send simultaneously. Also what connection are you using? Wifi? There is a whole lot of things that can go wrong here.

Comment: I'm not using any connection yet. It's all on localhost. That's why I'm surprised by the speed. I'll try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: So its 16kB/s constant? No variation? If this is the case the problem is not your code but a localhost config/setup/throttle issue. Do a test over a network and see if there is a difference.

Comment: What value are you getting for `buff_size`?

Comment: @Namphibian I've rewritten the service, so that now I have two threads: recorder and socket handling thread which communicate through a LinkedBlockingQueue of byte arrays but nothing changed. The 16kB/s I mentioned was an aproximation, in reality the speed slightly varies but is low nonetheless. After rewriting the service it's ~30kB/s - still too low to be of any use.

Comment: @fadden buff_size = 1280  I tried to increase it (multiply by 5, 10, 20), no change except longer time to fill the buffer and with too high values I get no sound at all.

Comment: I've modified the code and now it turns out, that the server's read is the one causing problems. It is incredibly slow compared to the send command (around 1000x). I always thought, that receiving data is quicker, not the other way around. Is there anything else wrong with my code maybe? Or maybe there is some trick for reading, which I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: How exactly can receiving data possibly be quicker than sending it?

Comment: It's not... Please read my post. The line System.out.println("speed="... prints the speed of sending the data, the line System.out.println("speed_sv="... prints the speed of receiving the data. As you can see at the bottom of my post speed is clearly 100 times larger than speed_sv...

Comment: I ditched java for C on the server side and now it's working full speed. I can even stream 44100Hz PCM with very few stutters. But if anyone has any ideas how to make this work in java (this IMO awful language), please do tell.

Answer (score 0):

That's no way to write a copy loop. You're allocating two byte arrays per read. Memorize this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it does not fix my problem and was in fact a previous version of my code, which I now realize I should have kept in my post while editing it.